# Index not defined while deleting element from array

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to remove  element from array if animation ends, but i get error: index is not defined.

How to correctly find specific index and remove it if animation ends?
They are drop() and remove() methods. drop() methods works well(i think) and  elements are correctly added to the DOM.

Single file component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="card" :class="classObject">
        <div class="card-image">
            <figure class="image" @click="randomImage">
                <img src="../../img/one.png" alt="Placeholder image" v-if="selected === 0">
                <img src="../../img/two.jpg" alt="Placeholder image" v-else-if="selected === 1">
                <img src="../../img/three.jpg" alt="Placeholder image" v-else>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content has-text-centered">
            <div class="content">

                <div class="title is-size-1 has-text-weight-bold">
                    <span v-show="score >= 10"></span>
                    {{score}}
                    <span v-show="score >= 10"></span>
                </div>

                <div v-if="score >= 5" class="has-text-grey">
                    ╮ (. ❛ ᴗ ❛.) ╭
                </div>
                <div v-else-if="score < 5 && score > 0" class="has-text-grey">
                    ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ
                </div>
                <div v-else class="has-text-grey">
                    (・_・ヾ
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="card-footer">
            <a class="card-footer-item" @click="score++">more </a>
            <a class="card-footer-item" @click="score--">less </a>
            <a class="card-footer-item" @click="drop" :disabled="score < 1">butt </a>
        </footer>

        <transition-group name="drop" v-on:after-enter="remove(index)">
            <img src="../../img/image.png" class="image" alt="an image" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        </transition-group>
    </div>

</template>



<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            score: 23,
            selected: 0,
            images: [
                './img/one.png',
                './img/two.jpg',
                './img/three.jpg'
            ],
            items: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        debug(data) {
            console.log(data);                    
        },
        randomImage() {
            this.selected = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
        },
        drop() {
            this.items.push(this.item);
        },
        remove(item) {         
            this.items.splice(item, 1);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        image() {
            return this.selected;
        },
        classObject() {
            return {
                hard: this.score >= 42,
                sixnine: this.score == 69
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>


<style>
.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(0vh - 500px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* pointer-events: none; */
    /* top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%); */
}

.drop-enter-active {
    transition: transform 3s;
}

.drop-enter {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
}

.drop-enter-to {
    transform: translateY(calc(100vh + 500px));
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find index of element in array with findIndex method:

```
remove(item) {   
         const index = this.items.findIndex(arrayItem => arrayItem === item);   
         this.items.splice(index, 1);
       }
```

Comment: Explain downvote. I'd tested the code above. All is clear.

Comment: I didn't down-vote (just reached this post now) but this usually happens when the answerer just post  some snippet without any explanation, despite sometimes the code speaks by itself.

Answer (score 0):

An Instance of finding the specific index and remove it from the array.

In below snippet, find the index which has `{ id: 2 }` and removes it from an array.

```js
const array = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, 
{ id: 3 }];
const index = array.findIndex((f) => 
{ return f.id && f.id === 2; });
console.log(index);
if(index > -1) {
// remove entry from found index
array.splice(index, 1);
   console.log(array);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes when you are trying to call a function when a reference is needed. Instead of `v-on:after-enter="remove(index)"`, try this `v-on:after-enter="remove"`. So, when the `v-on:after-enter` is triggered its going to call the `remove(item)` using the reference you've already given to it. If you are giving a reference to a function you only use the name of that function.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to make it more obvious what I want to do

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-vK3UTo/8wHbaUn+dTQD0X6dzidqc5l7gczvH+Bnowwk=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>life is vuetiful</title>
</head>
<body class="has-background-primary">
<style>
html {
 background-color: transparent;
}

body {
 width: 42%;
 margin: 2em auto;
}

a[disabled] {
 color: grey;
 cursor: default;
 background-color: lightgray;
}

.hard {
 border: 10px solid purple;
}

.sixnine {
 background-color: pink;
 border: 20px solid hotpink;
 outline: 15px solid pink;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(0vh - 500px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* pointer-events: none; */
    /* top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%); */
}

.drop-enter-active {
    transition: transform 3s;
}

.drop-enter {
    transform: translateY(0vh);
}

.drop-enter-to {
    transform: translateY(calc(100vh + 500px));
}
</style>
    
    <div id="app">
        <test></test>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
    Vue.component('test', {
    template: 
        `
        <div class="card">
            <footer class="card-footer">
                <a class="card-footer-item" @click="drop">run</a>
            </footer>

            <transition-group name="drop" v-on:after-enter="remove(index)">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="image" v-for="               (item, index) in items" :key="index" alt="an image">
            </transition-group>
        </div>
        `
    ,
    data() {
        return {
            items: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        drop() {
            this.items.push(this.item);
        },
        remove (index) {
            this.$delete(this.items, index);
        }
    }
})
    </script>
    <script>
        const vue = new Vue({
            el: '#app'
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```